# OData swallowing objects in navigation property

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem with an OData controller that is a little unusual compared to the others I have. It is the first one working completely from memory - no database involved.

The returned entity is:

```
public class TrdRun {

    [Key]
    public Guid Identity { get; set; }

    public TrdTrade [] Trades { get; set; }
```

TrdTrade is also an entity set (which if queries goes against a database). But in this particular case I want to return all trades associated as active from a run, and I an do so WITHOUT going to the database.

My problem? The following code:

```
  [ODataRoute]
    public IEnumerable<Reflexo.Api.TrdRun> Get(ODataQueryOptions options) {
        var instances = Repository.TrdInstance.AsEnumerable();
        var runs = new List<Reflexo.Api.TrdRun>();
        foreach (var instance in instances) {
            runs.Add(Get(instance.Identifier));
        }
        return runs;
    }
```

correctly configures runs to have the trades initialized - but WebApi decides to swallow them.

What is a way to configure it to return the data "as given" without further filtering? I know about the AutoExpandAttribute (Which I would love to avoid - I do not want the API classes marked with OData attributes), but I have not enabled Query, so I would expect the return data to be returned as I set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `Trades` property is not being serialized because the default behavior of `ODataMediaTypeFormatter` is to not follow navigation properties, regardless of what is in memory. You could override this behavior by using `$expand` in the query string of the request, or `AutoExpandAttribute` on the `Trades` property in the class definition, but both approaches require decorating your controller method with `EnableQueryAttribute`.

If you don't want to do any of that, you can still programmatically specify auto-expansion of `Trades` in your service configuration as follows:

```c#
// Let builder be an instance of ODataModelBuilder or a derived class.
builder.EntityType<TrdRun>().CollectionProperty(r => r.Trades).AutoExpand = true;
```

Minor issue: With the programmatic approach, if the client requests full metadata (e.g., `odata.metadata=full` in the `Accept` header), the OData serializer will *not* include full metadata in the auto-expanded objects.